# Flutter- how to navigate different pages by curved navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart

i am creating a flutter app  and want help on how to navigate to different pages. Also, when i tap on buttons of curved navigation bar nothing happens the icons not changing.

can u please help me out?

here is my code for the curved navigation bar

Thank u

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';

class BAR extends StatefulWidget {
  const BAR({super.key});

  @override
  State<BAR> createState() => _BARState();
}

class _BARState extends State<BAR> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CurvedNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: HexColor("#F7ECCD"),
          color: HexColor("#AE621C"),
          items: [
            Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 30,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 30,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.settings,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 30,
            )
          ],
          onTap: (index){

            setState(() {
                if (index == 0) {
                

                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');

              }

              if (index == 1) {
                
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/one');
                

              }
              if (index == 2) {
            
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/two');

              }
            });

          },);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.business),
            title: Text('Business'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.school),
            title: Text('School'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.black,
      ),
      tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return CupertinoTabView(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return CupertinoPageScaffold(
              child: Center(
                child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(index),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```